# Springframework: JSR 303 validation occurs before security validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-security

Using spring verison 3.2 and security 3.2

Hi,
I'm looking at an issue in our application whereby we're getting an HTTP 422 response when we should be getting an HTTP 403 response.
The issue seems to be that the JSR 303 validation is happening within the request handler framework before security credentials are checked.  This obviously leaves open a vulnerability as it is possible to work out what a valid request looks like without having a properly authorised session.

I've tracked the issue down to this piece of code in ServletInvocationHandlerMethod (spring's code):

```
public final Object invokeForRequest(NativeWebRequest request,
                                     ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                     Object... providedArgs) throws Exception     {
    Object[] args = getMethodArgumentValues(request, mavContainer, providedArgs);

    if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Invoking [");
        builder.append(this.getMethod().getName()).append("] method with arguments ");
        builder.append(Arrays.asList(args));
        logger.trace(builder.toString());
    }

    Object returnValue = invoke(args);

    if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        logger.trace("Method [" + this.getMethod().getName() + "] returned [" + returnValue + "]");
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

The call to getMethodArgumentValues results in each argument being validated.  This includes validating the JSR 303 annotations.

The call to invoke() will call the actual method on the controller which is wrapped by AbstractSecurityInterceptor and this checks that the request is authorised.  This means that the authorisation check happens after the validation check.

Is this happening because I haven't configured the interceptors correctly?  Should the security interceptor be wrapping further down the call stack?

Are we using JSR 303 incorrectly?

Is there another work around for this?

Comment: I've not fully understood your question, but some facts -> HTTP webapp security is based on URIs and is checked by a servlet filter ([FilterSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-security-interceptor)) **long before** dispatcher servlet even tries to map the request to any controller. So there is something fishy with your setup.

Comment: And I don't know if that changed in Spring 4, but interceptors on controllers used to be a bit anti-pattern for Spring. So usually you have HTTP security in the form of servlet filter (Spring's security filter chain) and then independent of that was application level security on service layer (AOP based).

Comment: Hi Pavel, We're using annotation based security on the individual endpoints.  So each endpoint is marked up with the roles that can access that endpoint.  Roles that should not be able to access the endpoint have their data validated, rather than rejected.

Comment: Annotation based security is implemented using Aspects (`AnnotationSecurityAspect` to be precise).  Aspects in turn require method parameters to be fully available because joins and pointcuts may require access to the parameter values.  Therefore, parameters are processed before invoking a method, which is when the Aspects would actually trigger.  Hence, the error you are seeing (parameters getting processed before the Aspects are applied).  See if moving the annotation from method to class level helps.

Comment: Annotation based security requires auto-proxying, which might not work for controllers in some configurations (for example with JDK proxying you will need to create interfaces, which is unnecessary overhead in my opinion). I suggest to you to use [HTTP authorization](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/) in front of your aspect based security.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answers.  I guess we have to change either how we do security or how we do validation.